# Can I allow registering users of a wordpress site to select their role?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I'm building an online store using WordPress.  I want to allow users to register on my site as either a *Vendor* or a *Customer*. If they register as a *Customer*, they'll get a basic account where they can shop, save items to a cart or wish list, and can check out.  If they register as a Vendor, they'll have access to create their own items for sale on the site (similar to **Etsy**) and I'm allowing this by using the **EDD FES Plugin**.

Currently, I have things set up fine to allow new users to register, but it only allows them to register as a *Vendor*.  I don't even know what I would do to make this work so that the *User Page* where the Vendor can set up their store items would show differently for a person who happens to be a *Customer*.  Currently, on the *User Page* I have just placed the `[fes_vendor_dashboard]` tag that automatically adds the dashboard for me.

Any help, advice, suggested plugins, etc. are all welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if you've seen Justin Tadlock's excellent [Members plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) but if you're working with custom user roles it's well worth checking out.

As for programatically setting a user role you can just take the user object and use the `set_role()` function to change their role to whatever you want as long as that role has been defined. For example lets say you have a select box with the name of 'user_role' with 2 options of 'vendor' and 'customer' you could simply do the following...

```
//Create the user
$user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );

//If the user selects vendor set the role to vendor
if( $_POST['user_role'] == 'vendor' )
{
    $user->set_role( 'vendor' );
}
//Else they are a customer
else
{
    $user->set_role( 'customer' );
}
```

Hope that helps

Dan